# cypher shortestpath query with filter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using cypher query for shortest path.

```
               MATCH path = allshortestPaths((a:Place { Name:'Name-1' })-[*]
               -(b:Place { Name:'Name-2' }))
               WHERE ANY(x IN nodes(path) WHERE x.Status = "true")
               RETURN path
```

Above query is filtering the paths after getting the list of shortest paths.

But My requirement is it should filter paths internally  with   `ANY(x IN nodes(path) WHERE x.Status = "true")` conditions, then among the filtered paths, it should find the shortestpath.

Is this possible?

Comment: what version of Neo4j do you use ?

Comment: On Neo4j 3.0, ALL and NONE predicates are evaluated during shortest path traversal.  But the ANY one is not evaluated 
See https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-shortestpath-planning

Comment: Thanks Luanne.we are using 3.0.3 version

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you get all shortest paths first and then filter for a condition or the other way around. As posted in the comment, the condition is used for the shortest path query.

Your query might be slow because all paths have to be evaluated to find the shortest path matching your condition (see link from comment).

If your query runs and returns something you are all good.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But when I replace ANY with ALL/NONE , it is going to infinite loop.what is the reason for this.

Comment: Maybe there is no path matching your condition.

Comment: if path is not matching, it should display no rows.correct me if am wrong. is there any other reason for this

Comment: Martin, I want achive the same thing(whatever achieved with the above CIPHER query ) using neo4j java api with FILTER.Is it possible.If Yes, can you give me some hints.Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea about Java